# Issue with Mongoose aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My requirement is for a particular user get all the expenses which are grouped based on the month and return the Month and the total expenses for that month.
I have collection something like below.

```
expenses = {{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bc0f74df46dae0bf4ffdc39"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5"
        },
        "date": "15-Mar-2018",
        "expenseInfo": "Clothes",
        "category": "Shopping",
        "amount": 100,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bc0f78bf46dae0bf4ffdc3b"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5"
        },
        "date": "11-Apr-2018",
        "expenseInfo": "mobile",
        "category": "Bills",
        "amount": 100,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5bc0f76cf46dae0bf4ffdc3a"
        },
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5bab847a5b0d2e2ce8b4cbe5"
        },
        "date": "18-Apr-2018",
        "expenseInfo": "Petrol",
        "category": "Fuel",
        "amount": 20,
        "__v": 0
    }
    }
```

Here is my Expense schema.
Also, Note that user object(user is a different schema which is referred in Expense schema)

```
 const ExpenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user'
        },
        date: {
            type: String
        },
        expenseInfo: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        category: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        amount: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    });
```

I tried something like this, but I am not getting any data. What is the issue here?

```
Expense.aggregate([{
                $match: {
                    "_id": request.user.id
                }
            },

            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": {
                        "$arrayElemAt": [{
                            "$split": ["$date", "-"]
                        }, 1]
                    },
                    "Total": {
                        "$sum": "$amount"
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

Comment: Try to cast the `request.user.id` to `ObjectId` in the `$match` pipeline because Mongoose wont auto-cast a string to `ObjectId` with an aggregation pipeline; the `$project` and `$group` pipelines can change the document structure in surprising ways thus Mongoose cannot infer what should be an `ObjectId` or make presumptions about the schema at any point in the pipeline. Try `{ "$match": {
                    "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(request.user.id)
                } }`

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot, @chridam. I was scratching my head for a long time, wondering what is the exact reason.